# SP2019 Server - MinRole - DistCache Complaining about memory usage on wrong server

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration, 2019, distributedcache, minrole

My newly deployed SP2019 environment set up in MinRole topology (x2 App w/ Search and x2 Web w/ DistCache) is complaining about high / not enough memory for DistCache service **on the wrong server**.

DistCache should be on the x2 Web servers. The service is reporting as correctly installed on these machines and not on the App w/ search servers however Central Admin health analyzer keeps reporting issues:

**Title**  The Current server is running low on memory.
**Severity**  2 - Warning
**Category**  Availability
**Explanation**
The memory usage on the current server is about {0}. This can cause the eviction or throttling of the Distributed Cache Service/

**Remedy**
Check the memory usage on the machine.And try to free up some memory or add more ram on the machine. For more information about this rule, see "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=224261".

**Failing Servers**
SPAPP01

**Failing Services**
SPDistributedCacheService (AppFabricCachingService)

This server does not have DistCache installed or enabled so I am unsure how I resolve. Ideas and advice welcomed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to services on server to ensure that the DistributedCacheService is stopped in the application server.

Generally please refer to the following articles to solve this issue:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/the-current-server-is-running-low-on-memory

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug with the Health analyzer itself, when Dist cache has previously been provisioned on APP server too, right after installation.

I was able to solve this only by running again Dist cache on my APP server and leave it as it is, only then the error has gone.

---

Probably, changing *localhost* to server's DNS-name in `C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\DistributedCacheService.exe.config` may help (as described here: http://fangdahai.blogspot.com/2014/12/appfabric-caching-service-stopped.html). Maybe Health Analyzer job trying to read this config from every server on the farm, looks for Dist cache service on *localhost* as specified in this file, cannot find a running service, thus generating this error.

But this config is different from one that is generated by the `Export-CacheClusterConfig` so I'm not sure that `DistributedCacheService.exe.config` is applicable to SharePoint. Anyway it's worth trying.